# Environment variable from docker-compose to .net core app

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose, environment-variables

I want to pass my environment variable(API_ENDPOINT) from docker-compose to my .net core API app.config.

docker-compose:

```
services:
  api_service:
        image: api_image
        environment:
          - API_ENDPOINT=http://service:3000/api/v1/
        ports:
          - "44399:44399"
```

.NET core,
app.config:

```
<add key="apiUrl" value="{{API_ENDPOINT}}" />
```

Its possible to get in .net core value of API_ENDPOINT from docker-compose?

Comment: Why you're not using the API_ENDPOINT environment variable directly in your code? Instead of putting it in the app.config?

Answer (score 0):

You can write an `ENTRYPOINT` in order to perform this transformation.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# Replacing {{API_ENDPOINT}} placeholder by the value of the variable
sed -ibak -e "s~{{API_ENDPOINT}}~${API_ENDPOINT}~g" \
  /app.config

exec "$@"
```

And add it in your `Dockerfile`.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1

# ...

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
RUN chmod +x /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Build and test

```sh
# build
docker build --rm . -t test-net

# test (mimic what is done on compose)
docker run --rm -it --env API_ENDPOINT="http://service:3000/api/v1/" test-net cat /app.config

# <add key="apiUrl" value="http://service:3000/api/v1/"/>
```

Comment: Your command `sed -ibak -e "s#{{API_ENDPOINT}}#${API_ENDPOINT}#g" \
  /app.config` not working even on windows I changed it to: `sed -i "s|{{API_ENDPOINT}}|$API_ENDPOINT|"` and it works on windows, but it still not working on my Linux container

Comment: @Chaosmordoru sorry :-|  could you please precise the base image you are using? It was not indicated in the question.

Comment: its asp.net core 3.1 image. I inspect folders in container and see that API_ENDPOINT is changed in app.config but project API call its still shows {API_ENDPOINT}. You can see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64576338/change-app-config-by-bash-in-linux-container (I posted here dockerfile, docker-compose)